# Index out of range exception when assigning query results to properties

Tags: c#, sql-server

Whenever I run this query and assign values to the properties on an object it always gives me an erorr with the ADDRESS_ZIP column. Whenever I comment that particular assignment out, the values goes to the phoneHome property.

Those two columns are "nchar" types so I think that has something to do with it. Can't nail down the problem though.

```
 public static Patient GetPatientInfo(string username)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = MedicalDB.EstConnection();
        string selectStatement
            = "SELECT PATIENT_ID, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, USERNAME, DATE_Of_BIRTH, ADDRESS_STREET, ADDRESS_CITY, ADDRESS_STATE, ADDRESS_ZIP" +
            " PHONE_HOME, PHONE_MOBILE FROM PATIENT_TBL WHERE username = @username";

        SqlCommand selectCommand =
            new SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection);

        selectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader patientReader =
                selectCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
            if (patientReader.Read())
            {
                Patient patient = new Patient();
                patient.patientID = patientReader["PATIENT_ID"].ToString();
                patient.lastName = patientReader["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
                patient.firstName = patientReader["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
                patient.userName = patientReader["USERNAME"].ToString();
                patient.DateOfBirth = patientReader["DATE_OF_BIRTH"].ToString();
                patient.addressStreet = patientReader["ADDRESS_STREET"].ToString();
                patient.addressCity = patientReader["ADDRESS_CITY"].ToString();
                patient.addressState = patientReader["ADDRESS_STATE"].ToString();
                patient.addressZip = patientReader["ADDRESS_ZIP"].ToString();
                patient.phoneHome = patientReader["PHONE_HOME"].ToString();
                patient.phoneMobile = patientReader["PHONE_MOBILE"].ToString();
                return patient;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma between ADDRESS_ZIP and PHONE_HOME (hard to see because you split it in two lines).

Comment: lol...that's great. I fought with that for like 30minutes lol. I love coding. Not being sarcastic either.